# Play definite frequency sound in visual c++

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-c++-2005

How i convert the sound() in Turbo c++ into visual c++ 2005?
I want to play a definite frequency sound through system speaker ?

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for [`Beep` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679277.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

...or the MessageBeep function.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680356.aspx